# How to generate temporary download link for file with google drive api?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I developed web-application to upload file to google drive and download from it with google drive.
but if i am using webcontent link for donwload file from Google drive then anyone can share this link to other. so can anyone have solution for temporary or one-time download link for file download?
or If the file downloaded by that link, then the link will be destroyed or not used anyway until a new link exist.

So is this possible with google drive api?

Comment: Application requirement only subscribe users can able to download packages with authentication. we placed all packages on google drive.

now when App share web content link to subscribe user to download packages - we must want to allow only that user to download package, not other users.
2 Issues for file download
# Download must start in browser bottom left corner
# Web Content Link must be Authenticate (only subscribe user can download)

Google Drive API - support such inbuilt features? If Yes, Please share or guide us how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no one time download link in Google drive.  If you create a shareable link as you stated it will work forever.   It cant be removed or disabled and it can be shared between users.

You might consider adding this as a feature request on the [Issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B)

Anwser: No this is not possible with the Google drive api.  Although i wonder if it isnt something you could do with in your web app and do a redirect type of thing.  Its just an idea.